# Razor Multi Conditioning AngularJS Data Binding

Tags: c#, html, angularjs, razor

In razor view, I have a table, inside one of `<td>` i need to check conditions and then if condition is true then do the appropriate operation and dispalay in `<td>`.also good to say that value to be evaluated in condition is angularjs data binding statment `{{value}}`, for example

```
<td>
if ({{value==aa}}) 
     {{value/a}} 
else if({{value==bb}}) 
     {{value*b}}
else if({{value==cc}})
     {{value%c}}</td>
```

tnx for helps.

Comment: ok so what is the question, where is your problem exactly?

Comment: u mean my question is not clear? @Coding

Comment: Yes its not clear, please elaborate more. mention any error and what you have done so far

Comment: inside the <td> tag of a table in razor view, i need to check condition for value to be displayed,if the value satisfies criterial then based on that i need to do some operation on that value and display inside td, @Coding

Comment: i tried <td><span ng-if="{{check condition}}></span></td> but did not work, maybe i did wrong . @Coding

Comment: if you just put `{{value}}`, what would be the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use ng-if directive, try this condition as below:

```
<span ng-if="value == a"></span>
```

Comment: as i said in above comment i tried it,
<td>
    <span ng-if="{{value == aa}}>
                    {{value /a }}
    </span>
<span ng-if="{{value == bb}}>
                    {{value /b }}
    </span>
<span ng-if="{{value == cc}}>
                    {{value /c }}
    </span>
</td>

it didnt work :(

Comment: yes please remove the `{{` and `}}` from the conditions

Comment: oh, let me try without {{

Comment: i tried but its not displayed, its because Im new in StackOverFlow... but it says its recorded and will add to ur reputation

Comment: or should i do something else to accept it as answer rather than clicking Up arror next to ur answer?